# How to add custom node module in expo/react-native apps?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create a custom plugin for android devices in react-native which can call user from app interface itself rather than using native android app and implementing the plugin in expo app by linking it in expo app.
But when I am importing the module in my JS code and using it the module is coming to be null.

This is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-react-native-call-app": "file:../react-native-call-app",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

// Plugin code for call app module 
https://github.com/NikhilOO7/react-native-call-app-module

// js code

```
import RNReactNativeCallApp from "react-native-react-native-call-app";
onPress = id => {
        console.log(id, RNReactNativeCallApp);
        RNReactNativeCallApp.callPerson(id);
    };
```